# Extending DateTimeImmutable calling __construct and __format

Tags: php, datetime, oop

I'm trying to use methods from the DateTimeImmutable class in my own class.

I don't understand why `return parent::format('Y-m-d H:i')` doesn't return a string `2022-10-01 15:38`, in the documentation it looks like it should: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php `public format(string $format): string`.

Why does it not return a string?

```
<?php

class CastsDateTime extends DateTimeImmutable
{
    public function __construct(string $date)
    {
        parent::__construct($date);
        return parent::format('Y-m-d H:i');
    }
}

$date = new CastsDateTime('2022-10-01T15:38');

var_export($date); /* returns 
CastsDateTime::__set_state(array(
   'date' => '2022-10-01 15:38:00.000000',
   'timezone_type' => 3,
   'timezone' => 'UTC',
)) */
```

**Final Solution**

```
class CastsDateTime extends DateTimeImmutable
{
    // public function __construct(string $date)
    public function __invoke()
    {
        // parent::__construct($date);
        return parent::format('Y-m-d H:i');
    }
}

echo (new CastsDateTime('2022-10-01T15:38'))();
// $date = new CastsDateTime('2022-10-01T15:38');
// var_export($date);
/* returns 
CastsDateTime::__set_state(array(
   'date' => '2022-10-01 15:38:00.000000',
   'timezone_type' => 3,
   'timezone' => 'UTC',
)) */
```

Comment: It is __useless__ to return something in `__construct`

Comment: should I be using an `__invoke`  instead?

Comment: `__invoke` is used when you call object of class like a function. Do you really need this? Why not use simple function which returns formatted string?

Comment: Also `date()` function still exists.

Comment: there's a casts property `potected $casts = ['field_name'=>CastsDateTime::class]`, and I want to map values to the casts. In my other class method `array_map( fn($k, $v) => array_key_exists($k, $this->casts) ? new $this->casts[$k]($v) ...`, instead of using a specific date function so that I can cast to other formats based on the field.

Comment: @u_mulder decided to go with the `__invoke()` method acting like a function call, but re-wrote the other method to `array_walk($mappable, fn(&$v, $k) => $v = array_key_exists($k, $this->casts) ? (new $this->casts[$k]($v))() : $v);`. Thank you for guidance on not using `__construct`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of a class has no return value. If you need a special formatting method, give that method a new name. Overriding the methods of the parent class is not a good idea. In this case, you don't need a constructor either.

Example:

```
class CastsDateTime extends DateTimeImmutable
{
    public function myFormat()
    {
        return parent::format('Y-m-d H:i');
    }
}
$dt = new CastsDateTime();
echo $dt->myFormat();
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/tQ87q

With your extension CastsDateTime you can of course also use all methods of the parent class.

Comment: Thank you, I realised that just using the parent::format() on it's own was a solution, in addition to changes that I've edited into my original answer.